# Async/Await behaviour of call back

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone explains me why `Console.WriteLine(t.Result)` line "blocks" next line `"I am done"`? From my understanding if there would be `t.Wait()` as shown in code this would be understable to me but in this case it seems `t.Results` acts as await itself. To me when line `Dim urlContents As String = Await getStringTask`  is reached it should call back (because of await) to Main function and proceed directly to line `Console.WriteLine("I am done")`, unless `t.Wait()` would be uncommented. What am i missing?

```
Sub Main()
      Dim t = Task.Run(Function()
                   Return AccessTheWebAsync()
               End Function)

      't.Wait() 

      Console.WriteLine(t.Result)
      Console.WriteLine("I am done")

      Console.ReadLine()
End Sub


Async Function AccessTheWebAsync() As Task(Of Integer)
      Dim getStringTask As Task(Of Integer) = Task.Run(Async Function()
                           Await Task.Delay(6000)
                                 Return 999999
                           End Function)

            DoIndependentWork()

      Dim urlContents As String = Await getStringTask 
      Return urlContents.Length
End Function

Sub DoIndependentWork()
      Console.WriteLine("DoIndependentWork...")
End Sub
```

**Confirmed that:** 
t.Result = t.Wait()

Answer (score 1):

The `.Result` needs to block otherwise it won't know what the result was. It even says so in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_1_Result):

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.

Remember - async/await won't change the order of your statements. If there are two `Console.WriteLine()` after one another, then that's the order in which they will be executed.

The beauty of async/await comes when you have several `Task`s that can run in parallel - then you can wait on them all at the same time. Or, if you have more stuff to do before you need the `.Result`, you can do that first and ask for the Result at the end (so that the task is running in parallel to your other code).

Comment: That's what i wanted to say that to me in this caase whether i would put either t.Wait or just trying to access t.Result will block next lines execution.

Comment: One more question: How then should i put result in Main from my task but not block   Console.WriteLine("I am done")  as i am awaiting for the second to be shown on Console as well?

Comment: Just swap the order - put `Console.WriteLine(t.Result)` last. Remember - after your `Main` method returns, your program terminates. So you must complete all waits until then, or they will be aborted.